# Send integer data from Arudino to another using 433 MHz RF Transceiver

Tags: c++, arduino

I have this code. This code actually communicates two arduinos each other with 433MHz RF Transmitter and Reciever. In this [example](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/rf-433mhz-transmitter-receiver-module-with-arduino/) code sends an char data which the lenght is been declared before but I want to sent integer data between 0-255 so I just need to recieve a potentiometer value which is between 0-255 then I will use the value for change servo motor's angle. How Can I do it? Thanks!

**Transmitter Code**

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actually used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
    if (!driver.init())
         Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop()
{
    const char *msg = "Hello World!";
    driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
    driver.waitPacketSent();
    delay(1000);
}
```

**Receiver Code**

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actualy used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
    if (!driver.init())
         Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[12];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
    if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
    {
      int i;
      // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
      Serial.print("Message: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);         
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to transfer the numbers as text you could use `sprintf` and `sscanf`. This is a portable implementation and allows for easy manual checking of the transferred data and possible resynchronization in case of data loss or corruption. Otherwise you could also use the address and size of an integer variable for the transmit or receive buffer to transfer the binary value which is platform-specific. I suggest to [edit] your question and add more requirements or background information for your use case.

Comment: This is clearly UART, so just make an array of `uint8_t` and store the raw data there. Since it is wireless communication over some hobbyist radio, you'll also need a whole protocol including sync bytes and CRC.

Comment: I'm a really ameteur one so I didn't understand anything you said. I'm sorry. I just need to recieve a potentiometer value which is between 0-255 then I will use the value for change servo motor's angle. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Transmitter:**

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actually used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

const int potPin = A0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
    if (!driver.init())
         Serial.println("init failed");
    pinMode(potentiometerPin, INPUT);
}

uint8_t data = 0;
void loop()
{
    data = (uint8_t) (analogRead(A0)/4); //Map from max of 1023 to 255
    driver.send(&data, 1);
    driver.waitPacketSent();
    delay(1000);
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actualy used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
    if (!driver.init())
         Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buflen = 1;
    uint8_t buf[buflen];
    if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
    {
      int i;
      // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
      Serial.print("Potentiometer value: ");
      Serial.println(*buf);         
    }
}
```

Edit: size_t to uint8_t

Comment: got this error


Arduino\libraries\RadioHead-master/RH_ASK.h:302:39: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'size_t* {aka unsigned int*}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}'

exit status 1

no matching function for call to 'RH_ASK::recv(uint8_t [buflen], size_t*)'

Comment: @spancer change buflen to uint8_t